# Context sensitive help of eclipse by hovering cursor

Tags: eclipse

After setting path of java doc properly to make it work offline,The Eclipse IDE is not providing context-sensitive help if you hover the mouse pointer over keywords.For example if I type "for" then  It shows "Syntax error in token" when I hover the cursor over "for" to edit java programming.

Comment: i'm not sure there's javadocs for basic structures, I think javadoc is more directed to libraries and objects

Comment: You don't get help for basic things like `for`, only for classes and the like.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody is here to answer my question.But I have solved it by my own effort.You need to click the mouse just after the "for" without any space,Now You can see the mouse pointer just blinking after the "for" without any space,now you need to press "ctr+space" to see the proper structure of "for" loop with code,now if you wanna edit this in your source then you need to press "enter".I know this is for editing basic things but it is very best for learning by developing the codes.All the people are saying that you can not get help related to basic things by using eclipse IDE but I think they are wrong because I am getting all the things offline when I need them.

Comment: You can accept your own answer two days after posting it.